# display input text as span, width trouble

Tags: css

I'm trying to make an input text look like exactly like a span. I want my user to be able to type text without noticing he's in a field.

I've almost succeeded, the last problem I've got is about the width of the input. 
The input text is wider than the text it's replacing.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akatsukle/eotd8p4n/). (You may click on "Texte" to type yours).

Here's the interesting css part :

```
input {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    border: initial;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea try fixed width for the inputs

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/eotd8p4n/17/

also you may try use the same width of the span for the input

```
$('span.width').width(); // returns a width value
```

using this get the width of the span and put it into the input box using JavaScript.

EDIT:
try this, if you want to grow the input based on text limit then you have to increase the size as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/nyitsol/eotd8p4n/25/

```
 var input = $('<input onkeypress=\"this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + \'px\';\" type=text>');
```

Comment: Good idea, but it's only partially solving the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Akatsukle/eotd8p4n/18/
The text input doesn't grow with the text inside, as it would do with a css solution, or if I were to code the page.

Comment: why not using contenteditable="true" in the span, it will do everything, no need a lots of JavaScript, btw i edited the answer.

Comment: Well indeed, contenteditable="true" is what I'm looking for. I didn't know about that, thanks :)